# How to loop a script through a list of tibbles?

Tags: r, iteration, purrr

I have a list of tibbles, `dfl`.

```
> head(dfl)
<list_of<
  tbl_df<
    x   : double
    y   : integer
    z   : double
    form: character
  >
>[6]>
[[1]]
# A tibble: 36 x 4
            x      y      z form  
        <dbl>  <int>  <dbl> <chr> 
 1  409100012 107403 0.005  107403
 2 1032400197 107403 0.05   107403
 3 3725600001 107403 0.033  107403
 4 4218200011 107403 0.036  107403
 5 4873700001 107403 0.0512 107403
 6 5305300007 107403 0.0075 107403
 7 6488100007 107403 0.036  107403
 8 7008700002 107403 0.001  107403
 9 7517400002 107403 0.05   107403
10 8265300001 107403 0.0074 107403
# ... with 26 more rows

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 x 4
           x      y        z form  
       <dbl>  <int>    <dbl> <chr> 
1   50700005 128928 0.4      128928
2  145900103 128928 0.0285   128928
3  183900065 128928 0.5      128928
4  214400008 128928 0.1      128928
5  546400001 128928 0.129    128928
6  683600191 128928 0.5      128928
7 1032400049 128928 0.5      128928
8 7295600001 128928 0.000175 128928
```

I have a separate script I have written that takes one of these tibbles, `df`, as the input, runs it through several transformations / functions, creates a new, almost identical tibble called `save` with column `save$cluster`, and binds `df` with `save`.

What I need to do is run this script through my list of tibbles, `dfl`, store new column `cluster` in each of the individual tibbles within `dfl`, and then convert the list of tibbles into one tibble called `df`.

Here is a copy of the script I need to apply, within a function `myfunction`, and how I tried to apply it after the function.

```
myfunction <- function(x)
{
  save <- unlist(unique(df$x)) %>%
    as_tibble()
  
  df <- 
    pivot_wider(
      df,
      id_cols = x, 
      names_from = y, 
      values_from = z 
    )
  
  rows <- df$x 
  
  df <- df %>% select(-x)
  
  df[is.na(df)] <- 0
  
  row.names(df) <- 
  
  df <- scale(df) 
  
  # Dissimilarity matrix
  d <- dist(df, method = "euclidean") 
  
  # assess methods
  m <- c( "average", "single", "complete", "ward")
  names(m) <- c( "average", "single", "complete", "ward")
  
  # function to compute coefficient
  ac <- function(x) { 
    agnes(d, method = x)$ac
  }
  
  coeffs <- map_dbl(m, ac) %>% 
    as_tibble() %>%
    mutate(method = m) %>%
    filter(value == max(value))
  
  coeffs <- matrix(data = coeffs)
  
  method = coeffs[2,1]
  
  # Function to compute hierarchical cluster
  hc <- function(x) {
    agnes(d, method = method)
  }
  
  # compute hierarchical clustering with optimal method
  hc1 <- hc(method)
  
  # determine optimal clusters
  elbowplot <- fviz_nbclust(df, FUN = hcut, method = "wss")

  elbow <- ggplot_build(elbowplot)
  
  elbow <- elbow$data[[1]] %>%
    as_tibble() 
  
  elbow <- elbow %>%
    mutate(slope = if_else(
      elbow$x == min(elbow$x), -elbow$y/elbow$x,
      (elbow$y-lag(elbow$y)/(elbow$x-lag(elbow$x)))
    ))
  
  elbow <- elbow %>%
    mutate(lastslope = lag(elbow$slope)) %>%
    mutate(nextslope = if_else(
      elbow$x == max(elbow$x), elbow$slope, lead(elbow$slope)
    ))
  
  elbow <- elbow %>%
    mutate(slopedelta = elbow$slope - elbow$lastslope) %>%
    mutate(slopedelta = as.numeric(slopedelta)) %>%
    filter(x != 1) %>%
    filter(slopedelta <= 1 & slopedelta > 0) %>%
    slice_head() %>%
    select(x) 
  
  clustercount <- matrix(data = elbow)
  
  clusters = clustercount[1,1] 
  
  # Cut tree into 4 groups
  sub_grp <- cutree(hc1, k = clusters)
  
  # Number of members in each cluster
  p <- fviz_cluster(list(data = df, cluster = sub_grp))
  p
  
  save <- save %>%
    mutate(cluster = sub_grp)
  
  rm(clustercount, clusters, coeffs, elbow, elbowplot, hc1, method, p, d, m, rows, sub_grp, ac, hc)
  
df <- rbind(df, save2)
}

myfunction <- purrr::possibly(myfunction, NA)

purrr::map(dfl, ~myfunction(.x))
```

My script works on one individual `dfl` object, but I haven't been able to figure out how to apply it through my entire list of tibbles in the way I described.

I have tried different variations of `map()` and `for` loops, but am not having any luck. I think I am applying something incorrectly. Any thoughts?

*Edit* Here is a dput of dfl... the script will work on one individual tibble within dfl, such as this dataset: `dataset <- dfl[[1]] %>% as_tibble()`

```
> dput(head(dfl))
structure(list(structure(list(x = c(409100012, 1032400197, 3725600001, 
4218200011, 4873700001, 5305300007, 6488100007, 7008700002, 7517400002, 
8265300001, 8301900001, 8301900002, 8301900003, 8301900005, 8301900006, 
8313500001, 8534800002, 8555600001, 8555600002, 8620000001, 8620000002, 
8758300003, 8790700001, 8790700002, 8896500001, 8916000002, 8916000004, 
9085600001, 9085600002, 9085600003, 9179900001, 9208200001, 9441800001, 
9565600001, 9565600002, 9754300001), y = c(107403L, 107403L, 
107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 
107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 
107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 
107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 
107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L, 107403L), z = c(0.005, 
0.05, 0.033, 0.036, 0.0512, 0.0075, 0.036, 0.001, 0.05, 0.0074, 
0.84, 0.0075, 0.05, 0.05, 0.0075, 0.0144, 0.033, 0.05, 0.0075, 
0.0084, 0.036, 0.005, 0.036, 0.05, 5e-04, 0.036, 0.02, 0.036, 
0.013, 0.005, 0.036, 0.0075, 0.01, 0.005, 0.05, 0.005), form = c("107403", 
"107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", 
"107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", 
"107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", 
"107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", 
"107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403", "107403"
)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(x = c(50700005, 145900103, 183900065, 214400008, 
546400001, 683600191, 1032400049, 7295600001), y = c(128928L, 
128928L, 128928L, 128928L, 128928L, 128928L, 128928L, 128928L
), z = c(0.4, 0.0285, 0.5, 0.1, 0.129, 0.5, 0.5, 0.000175), form = c("128928", 
"128928", "128928", "128928", "128928", "128928", "128928", "128928"
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(x = c(125801401, 144800345, 170600168, 170600181, 
170600217, 170600235, 221400012, 221400013, 221400014, 221400015, 
337700025, 337700028, 337700029, 337700032, 337700034, 337700053, 
337700054, 337700073, 337700075, 337700076, 337700077, 343200058, 
343200090, 352500127, 387600158, 387600159, 518500447, 518500448, 
518500449, 518500450, 518500451, 518500466, 518500467, 573600090, 
573600094, 578500066, 578500067, 578500076, 578500078, 578500079, 
578500080, 578500081, 736400030, 736400104, 736400106, 736400107, 
761600065, 862200045, 862200049, 862200051, 862200057, 862200066, 
862200067, 862200078, 862200089, 862200091, 895900052, 1032400095, 
1530000026, 4126000041, 4154700013, 4229100003, 4530900043, 4533700006, 
4533700007, 4533700008, 4533700009, 4533700010, 4533700011, 4533700014, 
4533700015, 4533700016, 4604300027, 4604300028, 4604300029, 5499800009, 
5861600003, 5861600005, 5861600006, 6248100001, 6383800026, 6947000031, 
6968100036, 6968100042, 7170400001, 7177000005, 7357800001, 7465500019, 
7465500029, 8345100017, 8345100018, 8345100019, 8871400003, 8911000035, 
9005200001), y = c(13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 13907L, 
13907L), z = c(0.98, 0.4, 0.428, 0.428, 0.4, 0.3, 0.453, 0.4, 
0.38, 0.43, 0.4, 0.45, 0.45, 0.4, 0.98, 0.98, 0.4, 0.43, 0.1, 
0.5, 0.98, 0.35, 0.99, 0.3218, 0.4, 0.4, 0.97, 0.97, 0.46, 0.46, 
0.4, 0.38, 0.43, 0.026, 0.017, 0.46, 0.46, 0.38, 0.97, 0.428, 
0.15, 0.4, 0.3218, 0.98, 0.98, 0.98, 0.038, 0.99, 0.4, 0.99, 
0.99, 0.45, 0.43, 0.99, 0.46, 0.45, 0.98, 0.98, 0.4, 0.312, 0.99, 
0.3218, 0.35, 0.223, 0.208, 0.888, 0.485, 0.104, 0.414, 0.676, 
0.333, 0.6899, 0.99, 0.99, 0.4, 0.35, 0.223, 0.468, 0.149, 0.99, 
0.4, 0.99, 0.99, 0.4, 0.4, 0.771, 0.99, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.43, 
0.46, 0.4, 0.4, 0.99), form = c("13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", 
"13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907", "13907"
)), row.names = c(NA, -95L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(x = c(1032400234, 1032400234, 1032400234, 
1032400234, 1032400234), y = c(21801L, 69149L, 69165L, 69166L, 
169101L), z = c(0.3, 0.0154, 0.0307, 0.0154, 0.041), form = c("169101", 
"169101", "169101", "169101", "169101")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
    x = c(67500055, 77700108, 77700133, 77700135, 77700137, 77700139, 
    104300134, 357300053, 357300054, 357300067, 357300070, 357300072, 
    357300078, 357300079, 357300093, 574100025, 581300127, 990200002, 
    1032400220, 3481000035, 3481000036, 3481000037, 5075700005, 
    6424000064, 6677700001, 6749600001, 6761900044, 7027100032, 
    7527700002, 8185700001, 9145200001, 9145200005, 9145200006, 
    9270800001, 9533700001, 1032400234, 1032400234, 1032400234, 
    1032400234, 1032400234), y = c(21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 
    21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 
    21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 
    21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 
    21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 21801L, 
    69149L, 69165L, 69166L, 169101L), z = c(0.025, 0.035, 0.0263, 
    0.025, 0.0263, 0.0278, 0.37, 0.045, 0.06, 0.015, 0.018, 0.045, 
    0.06, 0.045, 0.06, 0.08, 0.00667, 0.25, 0.06, 0.006, 0.006, 
    0.006, 0.06, 0.137, 0.94, 0.0625, 0.003, 0.06, 0.05, 0.045, 
    0.25, 0.002, 0.009, 0.0066, 0.015, 0.3, 0.0154, 0.0307, 0.0154, 
    0.041), form = c("21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", 
    "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", 
    "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", 
    "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", 
    "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", 
    "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801", "21801"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(x = c(46400699, 46400700, 46400701, 46400702, 
46400712, 46400715, 46400716, 46408142, 183900249, 183900251, 
183900252, 1032400207, 1032400222, 1032400223, 1070700067, 5248400005, 
7117300007, 7117300009, 8276000005, 8911000022, 9051100006, 9051100009, 
9092400009, 9251300001, 9251300002, 9251300003, 9251300005, 9251300006, 
9358500001, 9460200002, 9460200003, 46400699, 46400700, 46400701, 
46400702, 46400712, 46400715, 46400716, 46408142, 183900249, 
183900251, 183900252, 1032400207, 1032400222, 1032400223, 1070700067, 
5248400005, 7117300007, 7117300009, 8276000005, 8911000022, 9051100006, 
9051100009, 9092400009, 9251300001, 9251300002, 9251300003, 9251300005, 
9251300006, 9358500001, 9460200002, 9460200003, 183900227, 183900243, 
1032400185, 1032400188, 1032400209, 1032400221, 1032400235, 1070700068, 
1248700002, 5248400006, 7117300003, 7135500001, 7181400001, 8613000005, 
8911000021, 8911000024, 8987100001, 9051100004, 9460200001, 9460200004, 
9460200005, 183900227, 183900243, 1032400185, 1032400188, 1032400209, 
1032400221, 1032400235, 1070700068, 1248700002, 5248400006, 7117300003, 
7135500001, 7181400001, 8613000005, 8911000021, 8911000024, 8987100001, 
9051100004, 9460200001, 9460200004, 9460200005, 183900227, 183900243, 
1032400185, 1032400188, 1032400209, 1032400221, 1032400235, 1070700068, 
1248700002, 5248400006, 7117300003, 7135500001, 7181400001, 8613000005, 
8911000021, 8911000024, 8987100001, 9051100004, 9460200001, 9460200004, 
9460200005, 183900253, 1032400208, 1032400211, 1032400212, 1032400224, 
1032400229, 7117300004, 7117300005, 9051100005, 183900253, 1032400208, 
1032400211, 1032400212, 1032400224, 1032400229, 7117300004, 7117300005, 
9051100005, 1032400225, 1032400226, 1032400227, 1032400228, 6617100007, 
6617100107, 8987100002, 1032400225, 1032400226, 1032400227, 1032400228, 
6617100007, 6617100107, 8987100002), y = c(43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 
69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69105L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 
69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 
69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 
69149L, 69149L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 
69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 69149L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 
43901L, 43901L, 43901L, 69175L, 69175L, 69175L, 69175L, 69175L, 
69175L, 69175L), z = c(0.14, 0.14, 0.425, 0.425, 0.425, 0.425, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.05, 0.425, 0.4, 0.05, 0.1, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.425, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.05, 0.05, 0.12, 0.25, 0.048, 0.05, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.08, 0.05, 0.025, 0.025, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 0.075, 
0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.1, 0.075, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.025, 0.03, 
0.025, 0.075, 0.025, 0.025, 0.025, 0.1, 0.1, 0.03, 0.1, 0.02, 
0.1, 0.025, 0.025, 0.02, 0.1, 0.267, 0.12, 0.257, 0.4, 0.125, 
0.257, 0.05, 0.257, 0.125, 0.25, 0.257, 0.10725, 0.1072, 0.257, 
0.12, 0.2525, 0.12, 0.125, 0.12, 0.08, 0.257, 0.0531, 0.012, 
0.05, 0.04, 0.012, 0.05, 0.02, 0.05, 0.012, 0.03, 0.05, 0.1706, 
0.1706, 0.075, 0.012, 0.0506, 0.01, 0.012, 0.018, 0.008, 0.05, 
0.0797, 0.018, 0.075, 0.06, 0.018, 0.075, 0.03, 0.075, 0.018, 
0.03, 0.075, 0.078, 0.078, 0.05, 0.018, 0.0759, 0.014, 0.018, 
0.012, 0.012, 0.075, 0.24, 0.125, 0.257, 0.24, 0.24, 0.257, 0.24, 
0.24, 0.125, 0.06, 0.03, 0.125, 0.06, 0.06, 0.125, 0.06, 0.06, 
0.03, 0.125, 0.125, 0.257, 0.257, 0.07, 0.00027, 0.125, 0.025, 
0.025, 0.125, 0.125, 0.26, 0.00102, 0.025), form = c("43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", "43901", 
"43901", "43901")), row.names = c(NA, -157L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))), ptype = structure(list(x = numeric(0), 
    y = integer(0), z = numeric(0), form = character(0)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = integer(0)), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))
```

Comment: Try to do a tibble with tibble, then mutate with the function

Comment: @Bruno not quite sure I follow... could you provide a bit more clarification / structure?

Comment: have you already tried with lapply(list_of_tibbles, function(tb) your_modifying_function(df = tb, ...)), then you can do dplyr::bind_rows

Comment: A dput of the tables would help a lot

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. Anyway, I think your question can be summarized as how to apply a function to a list of dataframes and then bind those dataframes by row, is that it?

Comment: @eduardokapp I added the dput of the dfl object - at second look, I'm not 100% the script will work as intended... I'm having trouble figuring out how to join the individual datasets back with the original, storing the new column "cluster" in the original dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Apply your function to every tibble.

```
new_dfl <- lapply(dfl, your_function)
```

2: Bind each df to the next, using rbind. A faster alternative is to use `data.table::rbindlist`.

```
final_df <- data.table::rbindlist(new_dfl)
```

Comment: Thank you - I added a dput of the dfl object. I still am having trouble, but I believe I'm headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, try using `map2_df` with `map` -

```
library(purrr)
result <- map2_df(dfl, map(dfl, myfunction), cbind)
```